# Autocomplete with Firebase

Tags: autocomplete, firebase

How does one use Firebase to do basic auto-completion/text preview?

For example, imagine a blog backed by Firebase where the blogger can tag posts with tags. As the blogger is tagging a new post, it would be helpful if they could see all currently-existing tags that matched the first few keystrokes they've entered. So if "blog," "black,"  "blazing saddles," and "bulldogs" were tags, if the user types "bl" they get the first three but not "bulldogs."

My initial thought was that we could set the tag with the priority of the tag, and use startAt, such that our query would look something like:

```
fb.child('tags').startAt('bl').limitToFirst(5).once('value', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val()) 
});
```

But this would also return "bulldog" as one of the results (not the end of the world, but not the best either). Using startAt('bl').endAt('bl') returns no results. Is there another way to accomplish this?

(I know that one option is that this is something we could use a search server, like ElasticSearch, for -- see https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html -- but I'd love to keep as much in Firebase as possible.)

**Edit**

As Kato suggested, here's a concrete example. We have 20,000 users, with their names stored as such:

```
/users/$userId/name
```

Oftentimes, users will be looking up another user by name. As a user is looking up their buddy, we'd like a drop-down to populate a list of users whose names start with the letters that the searcher has inputted. So if I typed in "Ja" I would expect to see "Jake Heller," "jake gyllenhaal," "Jack Donaghy," etc. in the drop-down.

Comment: How many records are we talking about here? Are we implementing Google search or a realistic client-side auto complete?

Comment: Good question. For some things we were thinking about doing auto-complete on, there are 2 million+ records. For others, there may only be somewhere in the magnitude of 100 (different tags on the site) - 20,000 (names of registered users on the site).

Comment: I think I see where you may be going with this, though. We could absolutely do a startAt() and limit() and then filter out erroneous results (like "bulldogs" in my example) on the client-side. I think that for any size number of objects in FB, as long as we use limit(), this should be performant (right?). This is less good than having Firebase handle everything for us, but is still an option.

Comment: It would be extremely hard to answer this in a SO format for such a generic set. If you offer a specific case to tackle first, I can help you work through the details. Each one you've mentioned is probably different for "most performant". We can rule out 2 million+ as definitely an ElasticSearch/Flashlight project. 500k or less, I'd just grab them all and filter client-side. 20k names is what, 400k maybe? Here I'd probably just index or prioritize by first letter of the name and filter client-side from there, optimize as needed. Pick one and we can work through it.

Comment: Also, note that you can use [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) to get ElasticSearch results and still only interface with Firebase, allowing you to keep it simple.

Comment: Hey Kato, I added a short example that might give you something to work with. I'll also spell out a potential answer below.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old topic, but it's still relevant.  Based on Neil's answer above, you more easily search doing the following:

```
fb.child('tags').startAt(queryString).endAt(queryString + '\uf8ff').limit(5)
```

See [Firebase Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html).

> The \uf8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point
>   in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in
>   Unicode, the query matches all values that start with queryString.

Comment: While this example (and links to documentation) specifically addresses Firebase on web, the technique will also work on Android. You'd do the following: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("child").startAt("string").endAt("string" + "\uf8ff").limitToFirst(5).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( [...]);`

Answer (score 7):

As inspired by Kato's comments -- one way to approach this problem is to set the priority to the field you want to search on for your autocomplete and use startAt(), limit(), and client-side filtering to return only the results that you want. You'll want to make sure that the priority and the search term is lower-cased, since Firebase is case-sensitive.

This is a crude example to demonstrate this using the Users example I laid out in the question:

For a search for "ja", assuming all users have their priority set to the lowercased version of the user's name:

```
fb.child('users').
  startAt('ja'). // The user-inputted search
  limitToFirst(20).
  once('value', function(snap) {
    for(key in snap.val()){
      if(snap.val()[key].indexOf('ja') === 0) {
        console.log(snap.val()[key];
      }
    }
});
```

This should only return the names that actually begin with "ja" (even if Firebase actually returns names alphabetically after "ja").

I choose to use limitToFirst(20) to keep the response size small and because, realistically, you'll never need more than 20 for the autocomplete drop-down. There are probably better ways to do the filtering, but this should at least demonstrate the concept.

Hope this helps someone! And it's quite possible the Firebase guys have a better answer.

(Note that this is very limited -- if someone searches for the last name, it won't return what they're looking for. Hence the "best" answer is probably to use a search backend with something like Kato's [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight).)

Comment: I agree with most everything you've put here. For this sort of direct content search, ElasticSearch is the simplest and probably the cleanest answer. It's also grows with your needs as your app matures. If we are limited to a strictly client-side answer, I'd begin simple, as you have, with startAt() and limit(). Contains style searches could be achieved by simply paginating server data and searching it manually--a slow but reasonable process for such a small data set as names.

Comment: Will this work for 100k records? Has anybody tried with this much data?

Answer (score 4):

It strikes me that there's a much simpler and more elegant way of achieving this than client side filtering or hacking Elastic.

By converting the search key into its' Unicode value and storing that as the priority, you can search by startAt() and endAt() by incrementing the value by one.

```
var start = "ABA";

var pad = "AAAAAAAAAA";
start += pad.substring(0, pad.length - start.length);

var blob = new Blob([start]);

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var typedArray = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(typedArray);
    var priority = parseInt(array.join(""));
    console.log("Priority of", start, "is:", priority);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

You can then limit your search priority to the key "ABB" by incrementing the last charCode by one and doing the same conversion:

```
var limit = String.fromCharCode(start.charCodeAt(start.length -1) +1);
limit = start.substring(0, start.length -1) +limit;
```

"ABA..." to "ABB..." ends up with priorities of:

> Start: 6566**65**65656565650000
>
> End:   6566**66**65656565650000

Simples!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jake and Matt's answer, updated version for sdk 3.1. '.limit' no longer works:

```
firebaseDb.ref('users')
    .orderByChild('name')
    .startAt(query)
    .endAt(`${query}\uf8ff`)
    .limitToFirst(5)
    .on('child_added', (child) => {
      console.log(
          {
            id: child.key,
            name: child.val().name
          }
      )
    })
```

Comment: the key here is .endAt(`${query}\uf8ff`)