# For Firebase more customize & complex search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, firebase, search-engine, firebase-realtime-database

We are working on application & now we want to switch our database to firebase. Now the issue is that firebase is not support more customize, complex & deep search. I read some articles that they are recommending to use elastic-search for the solution. Now we have no option to integrate firebase with elastic search, is it the last solution ?

Comment: You can use [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight), which is a pluggable integration with ElasticSearch to provide advanced content searches in Firebase. There are some [other integration attempts](http://www.waltza.com/2015/07/16/firebase-elasticsearch-dummy-walkthrough/) as well

Comment: @val thanks. So the core firebase did not have advance search capability ?

Comment: @Kashif: you've asked the same question on the [Firebase slack community](https://firebase-community.slack.com/messages/general/) and got the same answer twice. Firebase has the exact [querying capabilities that are documented on their site](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries). If you need something not covered there, you will have to integrate it with another search solution. Flashlight and Algolia seem popular choices, but recommending anything is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506800/autocomplete-with-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase and many more

Comment: I think the question could be improved if you were to add what kind of searching you want to do and perhaps a small sample of your data and what kind of output is expected. Firebase has queries, deep queries and other methods for pulling out data but a big part of how Firebase works is how the developer stores their data.

Comment: @Val Flashlight requires one to have Heroku account