# Search all user by user's full name in firebase IOS

Tags: ios, swift, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` in my project. I need to filter all the users according to the text in `UISearchBar` and display in the tableview. I do research for the query in firebase documentation but I did not find. I just need the firebase query for partial string. Can any one help me?

Comment: Are you performing a partial string search? e.g. as the user is typing in the UISearchBar you want to autofill from a list that updates the list with fewer and fewer matches as the user types? Or do they type the entire string and search for that entire string.

Comment: hey @Jay thank you for the reply. Actually I am performing partial string search.

Comment: Firebase doesn't offer a way to do a partial string search (a like or contains type query). The caveat to that is if you are searching the first part of the string - there's a technique to do that using .startingAt and .endingAt with a Unicode char, \uf8ff. Also, you *can* set up a Firebase structure to search for a partial string. [See Autocomplete with Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506800/autocomplete-with-firebase/23510916#23510916) and [Searching in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867185/searching-in-firebase-without-server-side-code)

Comment: I solved my problem by using the technique exactly what you suggest. I re structure the database according to the edward suggestion. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have these in your firebase database

- firstName
- lastName

and firebase won't let you do multiple where clause, to solve this, just add a new field, so it will become like this

- firstName
- lastName
- fullName

```
ref.child("users")
   .queryOrderedByChild("fullName")
   .queryEqualToValue("your full name")
   .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

   }
```

Comment: @EdwardAnthony How will this allow the OP to do a partial string search as stated in the question?

Comment: @Jay If it's partial, you can just make the index yourself. For example, a field `first1Charater`, `first2Charater`, `first3Charater`, and so on. And you query it by using `queryOrderedByChild("first\(input.characters.count)Character")`

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query) ?

I think QueryToValue can be useful here.

Answer (score -2):

hello hope this helps you.. if this ans works then please make it correct so that other user can identify answer very quickly....

i hope i understand your question.....

```
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet var tblview: UITableView!
```

step 1:-make arary

```
let data =
["xxx", "india, CA", "pakistan", "usa",
    "china", "fgsfsgs", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
    "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI"]
```

step2:-  declare this variable global just above the viewDidLaod() method

```
 var filteredData: [String]!
```

step3:-

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tblview.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    filteredData = data

}
```

step 4:-use Tableview delegate methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredData.count
}
```

step 5-use this below method..

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) 
{
    // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = data //use your array in place od data
    } else {
        // The user has entered text into the search box
        // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
        // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
        // item should NOT be included
        filteredData = data.filter({(dataItem: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            if dataItem.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
    }
    self.tblview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @akash for your answer.This filter from the in memory data. But i need to directly filter from firebase database.