# Read keys StartWith some text Firebase

Tags: firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I need search keys Firebase. But I need find all keys start with specific text, example: "User"..

My database keys (example):

- User1
- User023
- User316551561
- NoUserkey

So, in this case only the first 3 keys are retrieved in my app, because they start with the text: "User"

How can I implement this in my app?

Android studio 2.3.3 . Thanks you!

Comment: Can you please give the code snippet you have tried? What was the error message?

Comment: I have not programmed anything yet, since I do not know how to do this...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a Q&A site, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance. It sounds like you need to do a course on programming before you start asking questions here, as we won't write the code for you

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if your search is case-sensitive and UserA and userA are the same thing, you should consider storing only lowercased forms as searching for *use*  will not yield the data at the key *UserA*.

But regardless, the solution will be something like this (JavaScript)

```
var ref = firebase.database.ref(path_to_search_keys)
var query = ref.orderByKey().startAt(text).endAt(text + 
    '\uf8ff').limitToFirst(some_amount);
return query.once('value');
```

Also see [Autocomplete with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506800/autocomplete-with-firebase)